# Left Outer join for unequla records fro two data frames in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frame .
Data Frame one

```
+-------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
|DataPartition|TimeStamp                |OrganizationID|SourceID|_auditorId|sr:AuditorEnumerationId|sr:AuditorOpinionCode|sr:AuditorOpinionId|sr:IsPlayingAuditorRole|sr:IsPlayingCSRAuditorRole|sr:IsPlayingTaxAdvisorRole|FFAction|!||
+-------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
|Japan        |2018-05-03T09:52:48+00:00|4295876589    |195     |null      |null                   |null                 |null               |null                   |null                      |null                      |O|!|       |
|Japan        |2018-05-03T08:10:19+00:00|4295876589    |196     |null      |null                   |null                 |null               |null                   |null                      |null                      |D|!|       |
|Japan        |2018-05-03T09:52:48+00:00|4295876589    |194     |null      |null                   |null                 |null               |null                   |null                      |null                      |O|!|       |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
```

Data Frame Two is

```
    DataPartition   TimeStamp   OrganizationID  SourceID    _auditorId  sr:AuditorEnumerationId sr:AuditorOpinionCode   sr:AuditorOpinionId sr:IsPlayingAuditorRole sr:IsPlayingCSRAuditorRole  sr:IsPlayingTaxAdvisorRole  FFAction|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T08:06:06+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T08:06:06+00:00   4295876589  195 16157   1002485247  UWE 3010547 true    false   false   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:48:33+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:48:33+00:00   4295876589  195 16157   1002485247  UWE 3010547 true    false   false   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:27:10+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:27:10+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:27:10+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:35:42+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:35:42+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:35:42+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:34:46+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:34:46+00:00   4295876589  195 16157   1002485247  UWE 3010547 true    false   false   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T08:10:19+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T08:10:19+00:00   4295876589  195 16157   1002485247  UWE 3010547 true    false   false   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:28:16+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:28:16+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:28:16+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-02T09:05:04+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-02T09:05:04+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-02T09:05:04+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:31:28+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:31:28+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:31:28+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:22:58+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:22:58+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:22:58+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:45:22+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:45:22+00:00   4295876589  195 16157   1002485247  UWE 3010547 true    false   false   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:11:26+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:11:26+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:11:26+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:00:45+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:00:45+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:00:45+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:36:47+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:36:47+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:36:47+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:01:52+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:01:52+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:01:52+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-02T10:28:22+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-02T10:28:22+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-02T10:28:22+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:52:48+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:52:48+00:00   4295876589  195 16157   1002485247  UWE 3010547 true    false   false   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:41:09+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:41:09+00:00   4295876589  195 16157   1002485247  UWE 3010547 true    false   false   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-02T10:30:32+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-02T10:30:32+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-02T10:30:32+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T06:56:32+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T06:56:32+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T06:56:32+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:05:04+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:05:04+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:05:04+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:38:59+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T09:38:59+00:00   4295876589  195 16157   1002485247  UWE 3010547 true    false   false   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:08:14+00:00   4295876589  194 2719    3023331 AOP 3010542 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:08:14+00:00   4295876589  195 5937    3026578 NOP 3010543 true    false   true    O|!|
Japan   2018-05-03T07:08:14+00:00   4295876589  196 3252    3024053 ONC 3020538 true    false   true    O|!|
```

Now i want to add all columns of data frame one two data frame except for the records for which three columns `TimeStamp ,OrganizationID and SourceID` is different .
So in this case Data frame one records will not be added to data frame two .Becase `TimeStamp                |OrganizationID|SourceID` columns are matching in both data frame .

Only 1 row should be added  which has SourceId 196 .

Does left_outer  join will work in this case ?
When i do that i get duplicate columns .

So in short Matching records based on three columns from Data frame 1 will not be added other than than all records will be added to to data frame

Comment: what should your final dataframe should look like?

Comment: Si ti realyl os muhc effotr ot tyep teh titel properyl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try `leftanti` join and then `union`df2,

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("TimeStamp" ,"OrganizationID", "SourceID"), "leftanti").union(df2)
```

Comment: No I got duplicate record if I use this